# How to run JavaScript File in android without Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio-code, phonegap

Hi I created my JavaScript project can anyone Tell me hot to convert it into apk without using PhoneGap i am using visual studio code to make my code.In PhoneGap many commands are not working can anyone help me in Finding and alternative. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use WebView and put your files in assets folder.

Comment: I cant understand can you say me clearly BTW Thank you for answering.